# Understand - Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: c#, mysql, database-deadlocks

I am using one REST API which will either insert or update record in mysql table based on unique key. While using this API parallel, in some cases i am getting error state as 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'. I don't have access to server for verification of logs.

While i am curious to know that even multiple callers are calling this API during that process if mysql takes row level locking for inserting/updating record also ideally it should not create deadlock and other calls should wait for acquiring lock.

For example caller A call this API and take row level lock on table 'tableA' then caller B call should wait till caller A doesn't release the lock and it shouldn't throw deadlock. Please help me to understand this.

Below is the table query i am using it.

```
INSERT INTO tableA (A,B,C,D) VALUES
        {{INSERT_CLAUSE}}
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `D`= (D) + 1, E = now()";
```

Unique Key On columns - A,B,C

P.S I have gone through all other suggested answer but nothing seems to clear this doubt.

Comment: you can try https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html but i din't know why you don't make d also unique. Beside hiw many ti9mes occurs the on dupicate at all?

Comment: i can't make the column d unique because it is not unique and i need value to be updated every time for d and also i can't lock the table as it is on client database. moreover my question is specific why is it happening ?

Comment: Is `{{INSERT_CLAUSE}}` includes multi rows data? If your answer 'yes' so data order will help to prevent dead locks

Comment: yes it contain multiple rows and i have maintain data order as well after reading other articles